# Block one thread R when any thread of the set {B} is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

My application has one long running, CPU hungry, thread (exemplified below by the `Runner` class) while a pool of threads needs to quickly build a page and then return it (exemplified the the `Builder` class). `Runner` is doing background media encoding and isn't time sensitive. `Builder.build_stuff()` runs quickly and is time sensitive so I want to block `Runner` from starting any new work if a `Builder` is trying to run.

I initially used a single `threading.Lock()` to block `Runner.do_work` but that limited multiple `Builder`s from running at one time. I made a simplified example below to show the strategy I've come up with; but I am not 100% sure it's the best solution or that there isn't an existing construct for doing this.

```
import threading
runner = Runner()

"""Thread that is always running"""
def run():
    while True:
        runner.do_work()
running_work = threading.Thread(target=run).start()

"""Builders are created for a short duration by an outside pool of threads"""
class Builder:
    def __del__(self):
        runner.outside_release()

    def __init__(self):
        runner.outside_acquire()
        self.build_stuff()

    def build_stuff(self):
        """Do build some stuff here"""
        return """thing that was built"""

class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.building_flag = 0
        self.building_lock = threading.Condition(threading.Lock())

    def outside_acquire(self):
        with runner.building_lock:
            runner.building_flag += 1
        self.build_stuff()

    def outside_release(self):
        with runner.building_lock:
            runner.building_flag -= 1
            runner.building_lock.notify()

    def do_work(self):
        with self.building_lock:
            while self.building_flag:
                self.building_lock.wait()
        """Do some work here"""
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you already mentioned this but I'll say it again for anyone else who reads this: Interrupting a process in the long running thread and re-starting it is much harder than dividing the long running process into chunks and checking if you should pause every so often.

I found your example a bit confusing and incomplete, so I have made a separate example demonstrating how I would solve the problem as described. I used a simple list protected with a `threading.Lock` to keep track of any running builders, and a `threading.Event` to notify the runner of when to stop and resume work. The most important sections are before and after the "work" in the builder's `run` method where it adds and removes itself to the list of running builders, as well as determining if it was the last to shut down upon which the runner is notified to begin again.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, Event
from time import sleep

class Builder(Thread):

    running = [] #list to keep track of any running builders
    running_lock = Lock() #mutex for running builder list

    def __init__(self, work, can_work_event):
        super().__init__()
        self.work = work
        self.runner_can_work = can_work_event


    def run(self):
        #before we do our work, add ourselves to running list and tell runner not to work
        self.runner_can_work.clear() #runner cannot start new work now
        with Builder.running_lock: #append and remove are not likely thread safe
            Builder.running.append(self) #add self to running builder list

        print(f'builder doing {self.work}')
        sleep(1)

        #this is not robust against builders crashing. Perhaps a better solution would
        #  keep track of thread id's, and periodically clean out id's of crashed threads
        #  from the Builder.running list

        #del isn't a reliable way ot determine when a task is done. Do this at the end
        #  of the work you intend to perform.

        with Builder.running_lock: #when builder is done with work
            Builder.running.remove(self) #remove self from list
            if not Builder.running: #no more builders are in the list
                self.runner_can_work.set() #allow runner to begin new work

class Runner(Thread):

    def __init__(self, work_to_do, can_work_event):
        super().__init__()
        self.work = work_to_do
        self.can_work = can_work_event

    def run(self):
        for chunk in self.work:
            self.can_work.wait() #wait on any running Builders
            print(f'runner working on {chunk}')
            sleep(2) #heavy computation

#example demonstration

runner_can_work = Event() #event used to notify runner of ability to work
runner_can_work.set() #set event to initially true (default is false)

r = Runner(range(10), runner_can_work) # range = dummy work to do
b1 = Builder('work 1', runner_can_work)
b2 = Builder('work 2', runner_can_work)
b3 = Builder('work 3', runner_can_work)
b4 = Builder('work 4', runner_can_work)
b5 = Builder('work 5', runner_can_work)

r.start()
sleep(3)
b1.start()
sleep(4)
b2.start()
b3.start()
sleep(3)
b4.start()
b5.start()

for t in (r,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5): t.join()
print('done')
```